# Why Angular ng-hide does not update correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to update a variable called hideProgressBar the Directive "ng-hide" in this view through the $ scope in my control. But it does not work.

The line below works:

```
$ Scope.hideProgessBar = true;
```

But the line below does not work:

```
$ Scope.hideProgessBar = false;
```

see the complete code below:

```
.controller('UltimasEdicoesCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer, $cordovaFileOpener2) {
 $scope.hideProgessBar = true;

    $scope.Download = function () {
        $scope.hideProgessBar = false;
        ionic.Platform.ready(function($scope){

         var url = "http://www.wgontijo.com.br/teste.pdf";
         var filename = url.split("/").pop();
         var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + 'Pictures/' + filename;

          $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {                   
                $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
                     targetPath,
                    'application/pdf'
                  ).then(function() {
                      // file opened successfully
                  }, function(err) {
                      alert('erro ao abrir o arquivo')
                  });  

          }, function (error) {
               alert('Erro ao abrir o arquivo');
          }, function (progress) {
                $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
          });
  });
  }

})
```

HTML

```
<div class="w3-progress-container" ng-hide="{{hideProgessBar}}">
        <div id="myBar" class="w3-progressbar w3-green" style="width:{{downloadProgress}}%">
          <div id="demo" class="w3-center w3-text-white">{{downloadProgress}}%</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Remove the curly braces inside `ng-hide`. It should be `ng-hide="hideProgessBar"`

Comment: @GentiSaliu did work but now the variable {{downloadProgress}} stopped updating

Answer (score 6):

You need to just remove the braces `{{}}` from `ng-hide="{{hideProgessBar}}"` and everything will work. The reason it doesn't work with the curly braces because the `ng-hide` directive is already looking for Angular attributes, so that will not tell Angular to that there is variable.

Comment: Works. but now variable downloadProgress in ng-style="{ width: downloadProgress + '%' }"> does not work any ideas?

Comment: Try : ng-style="{ width: downloadProgress% }">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="w3-progress-container" ng-hide="hideProgessBar">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-progressbar w3-green" ng-style="{ width: downloadProgress + '%' }">
      <div id="demo" class="w3-center w3-text-white">{{downloadProgress}}%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did work but now the variable {{downloadProgress}} stopped updating

Comment: Try using `$scope.$apply` on `$scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;`.

Comment: `$scope` in never needed in the HTML template unless you controller have something like `$scope.$scope = $scope`, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're right. I use `var vm = this;` and forgot about it.

Comment: but i need to use $scope.apply?

Comment: I think, my answer works. But if not, try `$scope.apply`.

Comment: here not works.  $scope.$apply(function(){
                        downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                    });

Comment: Try setting the download Progress variable inside a setTimeout callback function . It has to be set after the current  digest cycle completes . Also see http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/ for detailed explanations.

Comment: with $timeout not working too:    $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                  }, 1000);

Comment: Do not set it to 1000ms. Do not set a time at all.

Comment: Or try $digest/$evalAsync - see my link above.

Comment: still not work sad...  setTimeout(function(){
                      $scope.$digest(function(){
                           $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                      });
                  });

Comment: Could you provide fiddle?

Comment: @delver just the variable downloadProgress not updated

Comment: i cant provide fiddle now but in few hours i will can